# How to edit shell prompt to show time?

Tags: zsh, prompt

I would like to edit my shell prompt to display time. I am currently using zsh, though I would like the customize the shell prompt to show time.

I understand that an `echo $PS1` will give me the environment variable contents.
Given:

```
[%n]%~
```

Setting the prompt using:

```
setenv PROMPT '[%n]%t '
```

I also know if I type `man zsh` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> it will give me a list of formats I can change to.

Comment: `setenv` is a `csh` command. You should get a "command not found" error in `zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
PROMPT='[%n]%t '
```

`setenv` is a `csh` command. The equivalent in Bourne-like shell would be `export`, but here you don't want to export that variable to the environment, just define the `$PROMPT` *shell* variable (typically in your `~/.zshrc`).

Try `man zshmisc` and look for the section "SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES" (or run `info zsh 'prompt expansion'`) to see all of the escape-sequences available.  Also, take a look at zsh's `RPROMPT`  variable.  It can be useful and fun.

Comment: I read the RPROMPT is good for displaying time as well, it shows on the right side of the terminal or screen right?

Comment: I decided on bash, which I could add time by setting the environment variable,
`PS1="\s-\v-\t\$"`
though strange, the prompt does not allow me to type on the same line as the prompt, actually below it.

Comment: Also, what you have suggested also works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the system time in the zsh prompt here is the secret sauce:

- `%T` for the current time in 24-hour format => `13:42`
- `%t` for the time to appear in AM/PM or 12-hour format, or use => `1:42 PM`
- `%*` to display the time in the 24-hour format along with seconds. => `13:42:03`

I would highly recommend using `RPROMPT` to display the value on the right side of the terminal.

I have `RPROMPT="[%D{%Y/%m/%f}|%*]"`